# How to do advanced error handling in blazor server side using Nlog

Tags: c#, error-handling, blazor, nlog, blazor-server-side

I'm using Blazor in server hosted mode and I'm having trouble with an error that keeps getting logged.

```
An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. | System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'model') at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier..ctor(Object model, String fieldName) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier.Create[TField](Expression`1 accessor) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationMessage`1.OnParametersSet() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
```

I'm using Nlog, which is capturing all these errors for me but it doesnt give me any clue about which component has raised this error. So i'm a bit in the dark at the moment, I have managed to come up with some demo code which will cause this error.

```
@page "/Test"

    <EditForm EditContext="@_editContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
        <FluentValidationValidator />
        <label>Test</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@_test.Test" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _test.Test1.Test)" />
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
    </EditForm>

@code {
    private class VMTest
    {
        public string Test { get; set; }
        public VMTest Test1 { get; set; }
    }

    private VMTest _test { get; set; } = new VMTest();
    private EditContext _editContext { get; set; } = null;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _test.Test1 = null;

        _editContext = new EditContext(_test);
    }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {

    }
}
```

So the ValidationMessage pointing to a null object will throw this error, however I have triple checked all of my code and there is nowhere this could happen.

So does anybody know how either I can log a bit more detail using NLog about which component has thrown the error. I tried injecting NavigationManager into NLog using DI but didnt have much luck as Nlog uses a static Service Provider and NavigationManager is scoped. Plus I have only just started using NLog so i'm a bit of novice when it comes that part.

Or does anybody know how I could wrap a try catch around the razor code, i've researched into this many times, Microsoft's own [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) gives advice on which areas can cause an error to be thrown but i don't believe the offending code above comes into any of these areas.

Thanks any help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community! My understanding of using Fluent Validators is that they require a parameter when they are called, that is the type of the validator you are using. Your code example above doesn't show that, is it in your production code?

Comment: I think you have to set something in the MDLC before processing the page. You could render that then. See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Mdlc-Layout-Renderer. Maybe also this is helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#lifecycle-methods

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comments. That exact code isn't used in production, but that code does compile and run, if you remove the validation message for the null object. If you switch the FluentValidator out for the standard Blazor one, the same error appears. Its because the validation message object (which is not Fluent) its trying to reference a null object.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't come across MDLC, i guess i could add an override for NavigationManager and everytime the URL changes, use that to set the current URL for the log, since it seems to be scoped. That would at least allow a bit more narrowing down of the issue

Comment: See also - https://stackoverflow.com/q/72063711/193178