# Logging URL in Blazor Server using Nlog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, nlog

I'm currently using NLog with Blazor Server and storing generated logs in a database. One of the data points I would like to store is the URL that the user was on when the log was created.

In other asp.net core projects, I would use the `aspnet-request-url` layout renderer, but on Blazor server this always seems to return `https://localhost/_blazor`. Is there a way to get the current Blazor URL and include that in the log?

Comment: I've checked the Info on NLog and I can see no mention of support for Blazor.  It probably uses Middleware to collect some of it's data and that won't work correctly in Blazor.  Blazor routes it doesn't submit pages to the server.  My guess is some bits will work and others won't.  You need to access the NavigationManager DI service to get the current URL.

Comment: @Ogg Vorbis did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis cant inject NavigationManager in nlog.config, so I am guessing I will need to somehow configure it in Program.cs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, it doesn't seem to be possible to use NLog layout renderers such as `${aspnet-request-url}` to log the correct request url for Blazor Server applications, but you can still make it work by appending the request URL to the logger yourself by using the `${event-properties}` layout renderer (see code below).

The reason is that `${aspnet-request-url}` layout renderer searches `HttpContext.Request` to get the request URL ([NLog AspNetRequestUrlRenderer.cs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/blob/master/src/Shared/LayoutRenderers/AspNetRequestUrlRenderer.cs#L71)), which works fine for other asp.net core projects, but Blazor handles things differently.

In-case of Blazor Server applications, clients only send an HTTP request to the application just once (to `https://localhost/_blazor`), in which they download all the necessary files (html / css / js / images) and Blazor establishes a [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0) connection with the client. Once a `SignalR` connection is established, it uses transport methods other than HTTP (usually WebSockets) for communicating between the client-server and no HTTP request is made after that. All subsequent requests are made through SignalR connection and therefore, you always get `https://localhost/_blazor` in `${aspnet-request-url}` layout renderer.

As per the documentation, the defined way to get current requests URI is to inject `NavigationManager` in your Blazor components. You can get the `Uri` property from `NavigationManager` which gives you an absolute URI in string format. NLog loggers can be enriched with context information and custom properties (using `WithProperty` or `WithProperties` method) which can then be logged using [Event Properties](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer) layout renderer. So what you can do is attach the `NavigationManager.Uri` to your logger and then  access that property by defining it in your layouts in NLog.config.

##### Solution #01 Example:

```
/* Counter.razor */
@page "/counter"

@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
    
/* Define Logger */
NLog.Logger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    
/* Attaching a property to a logger returns a new enriched logger */
var loggerWithProps = _logger.WithProperty("navigation-manager-uri", navigationManager.Uri);

/* Use this logger which has request url attached in key 'navigation-manager-uri' */
loggerWithProps.Info("Sample message which contains NavManager.Uri property");
```

Now in your `NLog.config` file, you can access the request uri using the layout renderer `${event-properties:item=navigation-manager-uri}`. Your config file will look like this:

```xml
<!-- NLog.config -->
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="Console" layout="${event-properties:item=navigation-manager-uri} ${message}">

    <!-- Or skip logging this property if it is empty (uses ${when} condition) -->    
    <!-- <target xsi:type="Console" layout="${when:when='${event-properties:item=navigation-manager-uri}'!='':Inner=${event-properties:item=navigation-manager-uri} }${message}"> -->
    </target>
</targets>
```

which gives the output logs:

```
https://localhost:7123/counter Sample message which contains NavManager.Uri property
```

---

#### [Recommended] Solution #02 Example (thanks @Rolf Kristensen)

Instead of enriching a logger by attaching a property to it (which creates 2 loggers, one with your property and one without it) and using `${event-properties}` layout renderer, you can simple add `NavigationManager.Uri` into `HttpContext.Items` in `OnInitialized` lifecycle hook. Since NLog has [HttpContext Item Layout Renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-HttpContext-Item-Layout-Renderer) which can access `HttpContext.Items`, you can access it in `NLog.config` by using `${aspnet-item:variable=YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME}`

```cs
/* Counter.razor */
@page "/counter"

/* @* Inject NavigationManager to get current URI *@ */
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

/* @* Inject IHttpContextAccessor to get access to current HttpContext *@ */
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor

@code {
    /* Define a simple logger */
    NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        /* Add NavigationManager.Uri into HttpContext Items */
        /* This will then be accessible in NLog.config like ${aspnet-item:variable=navigation-manager-uri} */
        httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Items.Add("navigation-manager-uri", navigationManager.Uri);
        
        /* Or make it fail safe so that it doesn't give 'key' already present error when switching to multiple pages */
        // if (httpContextAccessor is not null && httpContextAccessor.HttpContext is not null && httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items.ContainsKey("navigation-manager-uri"))
            // httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Items.Remove("navigation-manager-uri");
        // httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Items.Add("navigation-manager-uri", navigationManager.Uri);

        /* Now logging anything will have correct URL displayed in logs */
        /* Use this logger everywhere in this component */
        logger.Info("This will have correct URL attached from NavigationManager.Uri");
    }
}
```

Now in your `NLog.config` file, you can access the request URI which you pushed to `HttpContext.Items` using the layout renderer `${aspnet-item:variable=navigation-manager-uri}`. Your config file will look like this:

```xml
<!-- NLog.config -->
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="Console" layout="${aspnet-item:variable=navigation-manager-uri} ${message}">

    <!-- Or skip logging this property if it is empty (uses ${when} condition) -->    
    <!-- <target xsi:type="Console" layout="${when:when='${aspnet-item:variable=navigation-manager-uri}'!='':Inner=${aspnet-item:variable=navigation-manager-uri} }${message}"> -->
    </target>
</targets>
```

which gives the output logs:

```
https://localhost:7123/counter This will have correct URL attached from NavigationManager.Uri
```

This solution is easier because all you need to do is add 3 lines of code to make it work and NLog handles the rest.

1. Inject NavigationManager
2. Inject IHttpContextAccessor
3. Add `NavigationManager.Uri` into `HttpContext.Items`

---

Right now these are the only ways to log the request URLs for Blazor applications with NLog. See [NLog Issue - Provide support for logging Blazor request information](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4997) for more information.

Comment: Very useful, thank you. So, seems like the easiest way to set this up would be to have a "Logging Component" that injects `NavigationManger` and contains a `NLog.Logger` property that fills the NLogger `navigation-manager-uri` property on initialization. I could then inherit that component in whatever page/component I want to do logging in, and just reference the inherited property. Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/Ogg-Vorbis/b24254ac60b2bc33c38ff0b8018a09b2) maybe?

Comment: @OggVorbis Maybe one could insert `navigationManager.Uri` into current HttpContext.Items (At `OnInitialized`). Then one could use `${aspnet-item:variable=navigation-manager-uri}` in the NLog-config. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetItem-layout-renderer

Comment: Cool ideas, I think both of them could work. Though making a `LoggingComponent` would require more code and we would have to use that in every other component and call the logger like `LoggingComponent.LoggerWithProperties.Info("Hello");`
The other idea of injecting `navigationManager.Uri` into `HttpContext.Items` in components `OnInitialized` would probably require less code and seems more NLog conventional and easy to do.
Thanks @OggVorbis @Rolf, I will try out both methods and see how they work out. Will update my answer after that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and for the suggestion @RolfKristensen . I like the idea of using `HttpContext.Items` as it allows for injecting the logger using the standard `ILogger` interface. I do wish there was a more elegant way that didn't require every component with logging to override OnInitialized and add to the items "manually", but this will work for now. One thing to make sure of is that the `navigation-manager-uri` item is removed when loading a new page, else an existing key error is thrown. An extra line of code, not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

The `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` library uses the `HttpContext` as the source for almost all of its layout renderers. In a few cases, `IHostEnvironment` is used. In this case, the property `HttpContext.Request.Url` is used.  Middleware is not utilized.

Perhaps examining `{aspnet-request-routeparameters}` could be of assistance?  I don't know enough about Blazor to know how it populates the `HttpContext`.

Comment: I tried using `${aspnet-request-routeparamters}` with Blazor Server application which uses `RouteValueDictionary routeParameters = context.GetRouteData()?.Values;`. Its empty.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative ways of retrieving Razor-specific details:

- Getting page name/path - `RouteData.Values["page"]`

  ```
  ${aspnet-request-routeparameters:items=page}
  ```
- Route Template parameters defined as part of the @page. Ex. `@page "{title?}"` or `@page "{handler?}"`

  ```
  ${aspnet-request-routeparameters:items=title}
  ```
- Alternative get page name/path from HttpContext - `HttpContext.Request.Path`

  ```
  ${aspnet-request-url:properties=path}
  ```
- If you have handler to redirect url - `HttpContext.Request.Query["handler"]`

  ```
  ${aspnet-request-querystring:items=handler}
  ```
- Combined lookup of Razor Page Handler Name:

  ```
  ${aspnet-request-routeparameters:items=handler:whenEmpty=${aspnet-request-querystring:items=handler}}
  ```
- Getting the EndPoint DisplayName - `HttpContext.GetEndPoint().DisplayName`

  ```
  ${aspnet-request-endpoint}
  ```

See also: https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=package:nlog.web.aspnetcore